# In an AWS CloudFormation template, how can I place an EC2 instance in the subnet determined by a Spot Fleet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I've specified a Spot Fleet *with a dynamic subnet* and an (on-demand) EC2 instance in my CloudFormation template, like so:

```
"Resources": {
  "myInstance": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "myFleet": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::SpotFleet",
    "Properties" : {
      "SpotFleetRequestConfigData" : {
        ...
        "LaunchSpecifications": [
          {
            ...
            "SubnetId": "subnet-1a1a1a, subnet-2b2b2b, subnet-3c3c3c"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each of my subnets is in a different Availability Zone, so e.g. `subnet-1a1a1a` is in `us-east-1a`, `subnet-2b2b2b` is in `us-east-1b`, etc.

I want to place `myInstance` in the *same subnet* as my spot fleet's instances to avoid paying for network traffic that crosses Availability Zones,  but I'm not sure how to do this:

```
"myInstance": {
  "Type": "AWS.::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
    ...
    "SubnetId": ???? // WHAT GOES HERE?
  }
}
```

It doesn't look like I can use `Fn::GetAtt` on `myFleet`, and even if I make `myInstance` depend on `myFleet`, I'm still not sure how to look up the result of the Spot Fleet's placement.

Can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What is your reason for needing this single instance?

Comment: It's all part of a clustered system (that I didn't design); the on-demand instance is the supervisor/manager, and the spot fleet is a dynamic set of workers.

Comment: Often the way to do this is with an election process. You launch all your instances as spot instances and you have an election process which decides which one of those spot instances will act as the master. The rest act as dependents.

Comment: I agree, but that's not how this software works, and is not something I have control over. Hence my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your spot fleet configuration, if you do the following:

```
"SubnetId": "subnet-1a1a1a, subnet-2b2b2b, subnet-3c3c3c"
```

then you're telling the spot fleet to place spot instances in **any** of those three subnets. It's possible that spot instances may be in all 3 subnets at the same time.

Since you have a single EC2 instance, your EC2 instance cannot be guaranteed to be in the same subnet as all of your spot instances.

Your EC2 instance can only exist in a single subnet, and you must either specify that subnet, or let AWS decide for you.

So you have a choice:

1. Specify one of the three subnets for the EC2 instance, this way, the instance will (hopefully) be in the same AZ as some of the spot fleet, or
2. Reduce your spot fleet to a single subnet

Comment: My understanding based on [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/spot-fleet-examples.html#fleet-config2) is that using the `lowestPrice` allocation strategy will force all my spot instances to be in the same subnet selected from the list (based on price), which is exactly what I want - I then want to put the on-demand instance in the same subnet.

Comment: Understood. The problem is that the spot instances are instantiated by the spot fleet after it's had time to spin up and think for a bit, which can be some time after the CloudFormation stack completes. Whereas the single EC2 instance needs to be located during the stack setup. Also, it may theoretically be possible for the lowest price AZ to change over time and for your spot instances to terminate and re-launch to stay in the lowest AZ.

Comment: That's why I thought about using a `DependsOn` to enforce an ordering, but I'm still not sure how to get the selected subnet value from the fleet. Could I fake it with a `CreationPolicy` or `WaitHandle` and cfg-signal?

Comment: You might be able to fake it with a `WaitHandle` or `cfg-signal`. But that's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Take look at this. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-waitcondition.html#using-cfn-waitcondition-signaljson You can pass data when you signal your wait condition. So you could make your EC2 instance DependOn a wait condition and see if you can pull out the data value.